# Why use a data class as a nested class

Tags: kotlin

I came across the following code:

```
sealed class PointOf(val location: LatLng) {
    data class Interest(val point: DbHotelPointOfInterest) : PointOf(point.location!!)
    data class Hotel(val hotel: DbHotel) : PointOf(hotel.location!!)
}
```

I'm used to seeing data classes used as top-level classes and not as a nested class. What would be a valid reason for using a data class as a nested class?

Comment: Probably just because of names? `PointOf.Interest` and `PointOf.Hotel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not a given `class` is a `data class` is a choice to be made based on whether or not you want the "free" default functionality that a `data class` provides (equals/hashCode, copy, etc).

A `sealed class` is one for which all possible subclasses are defined and "known", allowing the compiler to perform various nice things like validating whether or not a `when` statement is exhaustive.

These two concepts exist entirely separately from each other. You are free to do whatever you want for the subclasses of a sealed class, and that includes deciding to make them data classes.

So, to analyze your example:

The `sealed class` choice for `PointOf` will allow you to write the following code (assuming `pointOf` is a valid instance of the `PointOf` sealed class):

```
when (pointOf) {
    is Interest -> handlePointOfInterest(pointOf)
    is Hotel -> handleHotel(pointOf)
}
```

You do not need to provide an `else` clause because the compiler knows that the `when` statement is exhaustive. And you do not need to worry about forgetting this `when` statement if you ever do add a third `PointOf` subclass because the compiler will immediately know that the `when` is no longer exhaustive and will fail your build.

The `data class` choice for `Hotel` will allow you to write the following code (assuming `dbHotel` is a valid instance of the `DbHotel` class):

```
val hotelPoint1 = PointOf.Hotel(dbHotel)
val hotelPoint2 = PointOf.Hotel(dbHotel)

if (hotelPoint1 == hotelPoint2) {
    // will succeed, because data classes generate an equals() implementation
}
```

If `PointOf.Hotel` were a simple non-data `class`, that `if` check would fail because there is no defined `equals()` method and so you would be checking referential equality.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but referential equality is done using ===, so a normal class would not fail if you compare two classes using ===

Comment: Kotlin `==` is like Java `.equals()`, and Kotlin `===` is like Java `==`. So that `if` statement will fail (evaluate to `false`) if you used `===`, regardless of whether or not the instances were of a `data class` (since they are not the same reference). The `==` version succeeds only because `data class` automatically creates an `equals()` method that checks for field-based equality.